# Get products from url, that updates every 15 Min.?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, woocommerce-rest-api

I am fairly new to WooCommerce, so maybe I'm just missing a point. My client gave me an url to a csv file, that's updating every 15 Min.

The url is structured like: [www.domain.com/backend/export/index/products-simple.csv?feedID=25&hash=..](http://www.domain.com/backend/export/index/products-simple.csv?feedID=25&hash=..). followed by a long letter/number combination

So my questions are:

1. How can I import the products? The link doesn't end with .csv, so the normal importer doesn't accept the url.
2. How can I update the stocks and products automatically every 15 Min?

Comment: You will have to create a script to import products from `csv` and then run it every 15min with a `cron job`

Comment: Okay, I was already afraid, that I need to do something custom like that. I tried to google for an example/tutorial, but couldn't find anything suitable. Would you have a link/example code for me?

Comment: Use `$_GET['feedID']` get the value and query the database the use cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone interested in the solution: instead of creating a custom script, I used the WordPress all-import plugin: https://www.wpallimport.com/

There I could easily connect custom cron jobs and manage all the imported data.